# Better way to copy paste previous word using vim's default keyboard sequences?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Recently I have been documenting a lot of code which are usually in markdown files (.md). And I frequently come across texts where I have to retype previously written word. Like,

```
cp file_1 file_2
mv -v file1 file2
git clone --bare repo_name repo_name.git
etc ...
```

Currently, I have been using the following sequence to achieve copying and pasting the previous word without using mouse:

some_word <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> rest of the sentence.

**BUT** this seems rather having to press more keys strokes than the word itself (< 8 strokes), and doesn't seems like a wise thing to do.

**So the question,**

1. Is there a better way to achieving this using default VIM sequences. Kindly do not suggest `key mapping` unless there is no other alternative.
2. Can I copy-paste text without leaving the `vim insert mode`?

Comment: so by previous word you mean the one immediately before the cursor?  have you tried `ctrl+p`?

Comment: @Mass yes! And excellent answer. That's exactly I was looking for. Kindly post it in the answer with some cool info on this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to insert words from the buffer is using `keyword completion`.  This is done using the keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in insert mode.  The exact behavior depends on the options `completeopt` and `complete`, so I will assume you have set the defaults.

The difference between these is

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> targets words before the cursor ("previous") and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> targets words after the cursor ("next") and
2. using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> first targets the current buffer only but without <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> it targets all buffers.  This behavior can be changed using `complete` (see `:help 'complete'`).

Thus, by default, to insert the word before the cursor you merely need to type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> once.  The latter may be slightly faster if you have many buffers open.